# Product decomposition for finite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We say that a finite, simple, undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ is *(product-)irreducible* if it is connected and there are no graphs $A,B$ such that $G\cong A\times B$ (where $\times$ denotes the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of graphs).

Suppose that $G_i, H_j$ are irreducible graphs, where $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for some positive integers $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, and suppose that $$\prod_{i=1}^nG_i \cong \prod_{j=1}^m H_j.$$

**Questions.** Do we have $m=n$? And if yes, is there a bijection $\varphi:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $G_i \cong H_{\varphi(i)}$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: Doesn't "If a graph can be represented as a tensor product, then there may be multiple different representations (tensor products do not satisfy unique factorization) but each representation has the same number of irreducible factors. Imrich (1998) gives a polynomial time algorithm for recognizing tensor product graphs and finding a factorization of any such graph." answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, there is a counterexample on page 1518 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1968-151-x). Then again, I might not have read it carefully enough.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the simplest counterexample is taking the product with a point (a graph with one vertex and no edges). This removes all edges from a graph and thus there cannot be a unique decomposition into irreducible factors.