# $K_0$ of finite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, grothendieck-rings

We have two operations on finite graphs, first the disjoint union and the categorical product. I want to use these operations to associate a r(i)ng $R$ to finite graphs. An element of that ring is an equivalence class of a pair $[G_1,G_2]$ of finite graphs subject to the equivalence relation $[G_1\amalg G,G_2\amalg G]=[G_1,G_2]$ for any $G$.
Addition is given by disjoint union. Think of a pair as the formal difference $G_1-G_2$. Then the categorical product induces a multiplication $[G_1,G_2]\otimes [H_1,H_2] = [G_1\otimes H_1\amalg G_2\otimes H_2,G_1\otimes H_2\amalg G_2\otimes H_1]$.

*What is known about this ring (for all possible variants of the definition of graph ((un)directed, with(out) loops, with(out) multiple edges)?*

The neutral element of the multiplication would be given by the graph with one vertex and one loop. So unless you care about rings without 1, allowing loops might be a good idea.

There is a homomorphism to the ring of integers, that counts the vertices of a graph. But this ring homomorphism forgets a lot of information, so maybe it is better to define a ring homomorphism into a bigger ring. There is one into the monoid ring of $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$:

$$R\to \mathbb{Z}[(\mathbb{N},\cdot)] \qquad [G,\emptyset] \mapsto \sum_n \#\{\text{vertices of degree } n\text{ in } G\}[n].$$

Of course this homomorphism still has a Kernel, namely pairs $[G_1,G_2]$ where $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same number of vertices of each degree.

This question is inspired by [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457392), the counterexample $pt\otimes G$ removes all edges feels a bit like saying that there cannot be a unique factorization in the natural numbers because $0\cdot m=0\cdot n$ for all $m,n$. There is an obvious way to fix it for natural numbers (just disallow 0), but I do not see a way to fix it for graphs. This analogy lead to my attempt to define such a ring.

Comment: Have you tried other invariants like (virtual) Euler characteristic or Betti number? Also, it could be easier to strengthen formal differences to cofibration sequences. Like, given suitable map $f:G\to G'$ impose $[G'] = [G] + [\operatorname{cone}(f)]$ where the cone of $f$ is obtained by joining each vertex of $G$ with its $f$-image and with the same fresh vertex.

Comment: Doesn't every graph decompose uniquely into indecomposable (i.e. connected) graphs? In such "semisimple" situations, $K_0$ is just a free abelian group on all isomorphism types of indecomposable objects. The isomorphism is induced by taking $(G_1,G_2)$ to the tuple which counts for each iso type $H$ the number of components of $G_1$ of the form $H$ minus that number for $G_2$. This at least describes $K_0$ explicitly additively.